# Interrupting and killing everything for a complex, long-running task?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, lambda

I'm somewhat proficient in multithreading but for the most part I've avoided thread/task interruption because to me it is not a fun topic. But I have this Swing dashboard with a "PROCESS" button that performs a long-running task (which can run anywhere from 5 seconds to 7 minutes). It is a highly tactical application so the users want the ability to cancel the task at anytime, rather than killing and restarting the application like I instruct them to.

But I'd like to make this a bit more graceful and make the users happy. I've been reading Goetz' text for awhile, but I don't need very much sophistication in killing the process. It is one worker thread which can kick off several other threads (including lambda parallel streams), and all the needed objects and resources are created by these threads. I don't care about cleanup. Any objects these threads use are created by them and can be disposed by the garbage collector upon interruption.

The problem is there is too much complexity, deep call stacks, runnables, and lambda expressions to propagate InterruptionExceptions. I don't mind creating a flag that all the different worker entities (threads, classes, etc) can read. But I basically want to throw an unchecked RuntimeException, catch it on the Button's actionPerformed() method, and let everything die.

Is this possible? I want this to be simple, and want everything created by this worker thread to be destroyed by the garbage collector. Or do I have to explicitly kill all the threadpools, threads, etc?

Just to be clear... I DO NOT want the dashboard and the application to die. I just want everything created by this worker thread (invoked by the "PROCESS" button) to die and go to the garbage collector.

Comment: I supposed I could use Google Guava's EventBus to post an event that updates flags in every dependent class that the worker thread and its children threads are working in. That way, every  thread/class entity in the algorithm will stop their subprocesses, clean themselves up, and destroy itself, all the way back up to the worker thread.

Comment: Why not use FutureTask in the java.util.concurrent package?

Comment: Are the worker threads performing tasks on some object, or are they only doing computation? If you can guarantee that the workers never access any resources except for ones that become garbage afterwards, you might be able to use `Thread.stop()`.